# Dataplicity unable to access port

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am having a problem in accessing ports with my Pi. I am using dataplicity to access it online.

I can access my page with this URL.

```
https://my_id.dataplicity.io
```

Can't access when I use this

```
https://my_id.dataplicity.io:9090/
```

But I can access it in my local.

```
http://localhost:9090/
```

What could possibly be the problem here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At the present time wormhole forwards HTTP traffic to port 80 on your device but forwarding to other ports is not something that can be achieved by default.

The port forwarding feature is coming as part of our PRO pricing plan in future.

As an interim workaround, it is possible to redirect port 80 on your Pi to another local port on your Pi using a reverse proxy (for example using nginx). Although wormhole itself will still communicate with port 80 on your device, nginx could listen on port 80 and forward this to another local port of your choosing. Here's a nice article that could get you started:
https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-reverse-proxy/